# Get Only a Part of the Url with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hello My **Url** is as follows mysite.com/About how could I create a script capable of taking only the **Url** part after **/** ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Hint: I would look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp (hint#2: split("/") )

Comment: you should search how to get uri param in javascript

Comment: In what context are you trying to accomplish this? Are you given an input to parse, or are you trying to get the location path with a browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this brother. Thank you.

```js
let path = window.location.pathname;

path = path.split('/').filter((el, index) => index !== 0).join('/');

console.log(path);
```

Comment: @Nicolas Miranda Baiger Here's a change in the upper solution (inside the join()). Please check it again. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `window.location.pathname` to get the path.